# Iteration of 2D array for an advection-diffusion model takes too long

Tags: python, for-loop, indices

I'm trying to model 2D advection-diffusion in Python and got into a trouble.

I used indicies and nested for loops to manipulate the values inside my 2d array which contains concentration of certain particles, and it is now taking forever to iterate.
Is there more efficient way for the iteration?

Many thanks in advance,

```
# Initialize u
    u_UPW = np.zeros((Nx+1,Ny+1))

    # Initial conditions  
    u_UPW[:] = u0

    # Time loop
    for n in range(num_timesteps):

        # Impose boundary conditions
        # Dirichlet
        u_UPW[range(0, int(Ny/3)),0] = u_dir[0]
        u_UPW[range(int(Ny/3), int(Ny*2/3)+1),0] = u_dir[1]
        u_UPW[range(int(Ny*2/3)+1, Ny+1),0] = u_dir[2]
        
        #Neumann
        u_UPW[Ny-1,:] = u_UPW[Ny,:] + dy*u_neu[0]
        u_UPW[1,:] = u_UPW[0,:] - dy*u_neu[1]
        u_UPW[:,Nx-1] = u_UPW[:,Nx] - dx*u_neu[2]

        # Compute u @ n+1
        l,j = np.indices(u_UPW.shape)
        for l in range(1,Nx):
            for j in range(1,Ny):
                u_UPW[l,j] = u_UPW[l,j]
                + dt*(mu[0]*((u_UPW[l+1,j]-2*u_UPW[l,j]+u_UPW[l-1,j])/dx**2
                            +(u_UPW[l,j+1]-2*u_UPW[l,j]+u_UPW[l,j-1])/dy**2)
                        - u*(u_UPW[l,j]-u_UPW[l-1,j])/dx 
                        - v*(u_UPW[l,j]-u_UPW[l,j-1])/dy)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming `dt`, `mu[0]`, `dx`, `dy`, `u`, `v` are scalars.  You can eliminate the inner two loops just by using the same formula with the `u_UPW` array shifted up or down, or left or right, by 1, based on the indexing you need.

For example, instead of `u_UPW[l,j]`, just use `u_UPW[1:Nx-1,1:Ny-1]`, and instead of `u_UPW[l+1,j]` use `u_UPW[2:Nx,1:Ny-1]`.  All elements in the expression will be an array of size `Nx-2` x `Ny-2`, and that is used to update `u_UPW[1:Nx-1,1:Ny-1]` each iteration of the outer loop.

By the way, your scalar code potentially has a bug because you are updating `u_UPW` in-place as you go. So later calculations will use the new value of cells above or to the left. You can fix that by putting the newly computed values in a different array, and then assigning `u_UPW` after the double-inner loop. This problem won't happen when you do the array calculation in one go.

Comment: Shouldn't it be u_UPW[1:Nx,1:Ny] instead of u_UPW[l,j]?

Comment: And yes, I think I should assign another matrix cause the values are not updating. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Yes, I just realized the arrays are size `Nx+1` x `Ny+1`; I was looking at your `range` expressions, which imply the arrays are size `Nx` x `Ny` (that's another bug in your original code - the 2nd arg of `range` should be 1 more, since it should update everything except the borders). So if you want to use your convention, add 1 to `Nx` and `Ny` everywhere in my answer.  But imho it would be clearer if `Nx` and `Ny` were indeed the array sizes.